# DD-WRT sends itself as the DNS server to DHC clients

Tags: dns, dhcp, dd-wrt

I'm using DD-WRT on my router (version DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/11/14) mega).  WAN is configured to have static IP and LAN is configured to have a DHCP server provide addresses/DNS, etc to clients.  All of this works fine.  However I am struggling to fix one specific thing.  I have a DNS server running on my local network, at address 192.168.1.253 - and I want that DNS server to be set as the primary DNS for DHCP clients.  I entered this DNS server as the local DNS server in the LAN settings:

[image]

[image]

Now when clients connect to the router, they do get an IP address from the DHCP and the local DNS server, however they also get the router itself as the primary DNS server and my local DNS as the secondary.  All DNS queries go directly to the router, which then uses external DNS servers, thus making the local DNS totally useless.

How can I force DD-WRT to *not* send itself as a DNS server?  Or, better yet, disable DNS server on the DD-WRT altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! I totally missed the *Services* tab in the admin GUI.  There I disabled dnsMasq - and everything is now hunky dory.